# Non Numeric error while creating empty columns in data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to create additional empty columns - 104 columns -  in an existing data frame
the class of data frame is as follows:
"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

```
              df1 <- data.frame(ROW_ID = c("23416","23416","23416"),
              Process_ID = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Operation_Code = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Resource_Group_Code = c("BD","BD","BT"),
              Location_Code = c("JS","JS","JS"),
              Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B-T234"),
              Resource_Desc = c("699","699","699"),
              iDeleteFlag = c("N","N","N"),
              Attribute_Code = c("RA002","RA002","RA002"),
              Attribute_Value = c("266","269","298"),
              Capacity_Type = c("s","s","s"),
              Planning_Version = c("PDMT","PDMT","PDMT"),
              Valid_From = c("2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-04-01"),
              Valid_To = c("2012-07-01", "2012-08-01", "2012-09-01"))
```

It has columns which are "chr", integer64, and Date classes

My code for creating empty column is as follows:

```
         df1[15:118] <- sapply(1:104, "+", df1[[1]])
```

The code is giving out following error:

```
         Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Please help
What error I m doing

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You may need to use pull() to grab a single column since it's a tibble.

Comment: Can you explain in natural language what you think that code should be doing. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: I need to create additional columns - 104 columns -  to existing data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ROW_ID is defined as character and NOT a number. Hence the + is failing

Just change

```
ROW_ID = c("23416","23416","23416")
```

to

```
ROW_ID = c(23416,23416,23416)
```

your code will work

Full code is here:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(ROW_ID = c(23416,23416,23416),
                    Process_ID = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
                    Operation_Code = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
                    Resource_Group_Code = c("BD","BD","BT"),
                    Location_Code = c("JS","JS","JS"),
                    Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B-T234"),
                    Resource_Desc = c("699","699","699"),
                    iDeleteFlag = c("N","N","N"),
                    Attribute_Code = c("RA002","RA002","RA002"),
                    Attribute_Value = c("266","269","298"),
                    Capacity_Type = c("s","s","s"),
                    Planning_Version = c("PDMT","PDMT","PDMT"),
                    Valid_From = c("2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-04-01"),
                    Valid_To = c("2012-07-01", "2012-08-01", "2012-09-01"))
  
  df1[15:118] <- sapply(1:104, "+", df1[[1]])
```